# check compiler version in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Im writing application in c++ and after try to run built (in debug mode) application on another machine I had error  (The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorect). I realised that there are missed DLLs from windows\WinSxS\

But I dont really know which folder contains what I really need and secondly I dont know how to check my compiler version in visual studio.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with your runtime library set to multi threaded instead of multi threaded DLL.

1) Right click on your project, click on properties
2) Under Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation
3) Change the Runtime Library value to be Multi Threaded Debug (if in debug) or Multi Threaded Release (if in release)

Otherwise you may want to install the [Visual Studio 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en)

You can also check to make sure both computers that have VS are running VS 2008 SP1 update.

Comment: I have this setting already set with that value, any other hints ?

Comment: @snorlaks: Try installing the VS redistributable pacakge.

Comment: @snorlaks: Maybe also upgrade to SP1 on both computers.

Comment: But what If I cant install it on the computer that I want to run on ?

I finished my application and want to give it someone who doesnt havy visual studio or anything like that I make him able to run that app on his computer

Comment: @snorlaks: Then you should compile as release and put the setting as I described above.

Comment: Ok, I installed VS redistributable package but it still doesnt work. I cant create release version for some reasons.

Comment: @snorlaks: what is the error, why can't you create a release version? Make sure all your libraries of your solution that you are linking to have that same setting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there are no "redistributable" debug versions of the necessary libraries.  You would have to have VS2008/C++ installed on the other PC with the problem.

If VS is NOT installed on the other PC, either install it, or build the debug database with the release version of your APP, then debug it remotely from your development machine.

Comment: I dont need to debug It, I only want to create version which may be run on another machine

Comment: I would build the release version, then, and copy that to the other PC.  If you are still missing the required Microsoft DLLs, there is a vcredist_x86.exe file for VS2008 available off the MS website (somewhere) which will install the necessary system DLLs that are required.